# How to pass a raised error on a singular matrix of np.linalg.inv function?

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling

I created a singular matrix.

```py
mat = np.array([[   1,    8,   50],
 [   8,   64,  400],
 [  50,  400, 2500]])
```

Knowing already that creation of the inverse of `mat` will raise a LinAlgError, my aim of this is to pass the exception by the `try` and `exception` process.

So I tried, this :

```
try:
    np.linalg.inv(mat)
except LinAlgError:
    print('yes')
```

and this :

```
try:
    np.linalg.inv(mat)
except LinAlgError("Singular matrix"):
    print('yes')
```

and this:

```
try:
    np.linalg.inv(mat)
except numpy.linalg.LinAlgError:
    print('yes')
```

I always get the same stackoverflow for the several tries saying that i created a exception by trying to handle the first exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-18-de9bc8aa3ed1>", line 2, in <module>
    np.linalg.inv(mat)
  File "C:\Users\Azerty\PycharmProjects\OptionsHedgeFund\venv37\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 551, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "C:\Users\Azerty\PycharmProjects\OptionsHedgeFund\venv37\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 97, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Azerty\PycharmProjects\OptionsHedgeFund\venv37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-18-de9bc8aa3ed1>", line 3, in <module>
    except numpy.linalg.LinAlgError:
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
```

Do you know how to define the `LinAlgError` in `exception ... :` ?

Comment: Take a look at the message, `NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined`. Do you remember what your import looked like? Do you remember how you used `np` instead of `numpy` earlier?

Comment: Thank you about the ```np```, it is indeed how ```numpy``` is imported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference it properly, like:

```
try:
    np.linalg.inv(mat)
except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
    print('yes')
```

The reason the last attempt failed was because you imported the `numpy` library as `np`, not as `numpy`. So that means that `numpy.linalg` makes no sense, since the identifier `numpy` does not exists.

Comment: ```except np.linalg.LingAlgError:
AttributeError: module 'numpy.linalg' has no attribute 'LingAlgError'```

Comment: @Azertux0: `Ling`?

Comment: @Azertux0: what version of numpy do you use? Perhaps `np.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError` works. Locally `np.linalg.LinAlgError` works.

Comment: my bad, thank you guys, it's finally working ```np.linalg.LinAlgError``` is the right one